# Retrieve more than 1 output from native.dll file

Tags: c#, dll, output, native

I have native.dll file created as a result to deployment matlab function i use the native file in c# project 
the matlab function has 2 output

```
[ID,reco_ratio] = Orintation(Query_images,target_images)
```

when i call the function from c# project (using native file)
i try to retrieve the 2 output

```
Orintation_class temp = new Orintation_class();
object temp2 = temp.Orintation(Query_images, Query_images);
Double[,] q = temp2 as Double[,];
```

but the returned value is only the first output

so , How can i retrieve the 2 outputs ?

Comment: I suggest you debug and look at the actual type of `temp2` and then cast appropriately. `Double [,]` is a two-dimensional array. Your result seems to be a single dimensional array with two values, or maybe a tuple (I'm not familiar with matlab).

Comment: i solved it by combining  the 2 outputs in 1 returned array